Transparency Issue With Overlaid Shader
So I'm stuck on getting a surface imperfection texture to be masked over my other procedural shader, anything I try it comes out with the black background or if it is transparent, it's because it's making my object see-through instead of overlaying on top of the shader. For some reason my blending mode is stuck on Alpha Hashed and won't change to Opaque. I am using Cycles.
I'm not sure where the problem may be, so if there is more information needed do let me know and I will update my post, thank you so much.

Edit: Well I had a lack of thought moment here, but upon deliberation I realized my folly, I needed to do a Transparent Shader for my mask before adding into my main shader.

